# Formula for the total number of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers, set-partition

I am trying to tackle the following exercise from 
***Norman L. Biggs, Discrete Mathematics*** , p.91

> Suppose we are given a partition of the $n$-set $X$ into $k$ parts, and we delete the part containing a given element $x$. We get a partition of a subset $Y$ of $X$ into $k-1$ parts, where $r=|Y|$ is in the range $0\leq r \leq n-1$. Use this idea to show that 
>   $$S(n,k) = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{r}S(r, k-1)$$

$S(n,k)$ is the total number of partitions of an n-set $X$ into $k$ parts, and the following recursive formula is provided

$$S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + kS(n-1,k)  ; \space \space (2 \leq k \leq n-1)$$

---

Any hints on how to begin tackling this exercse will be greatly appreciated ! I know that I need to show that the combinatorial formula is equivalent to the recursive definition given above (and which appears as a proven theorem in the book) ... but not sure what the best approach is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concreteness, suppose we are partitioning the set of integers $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Let $r$ be fixed and denote the number of elements *not* in the same subset as element $1$. First, choose which $r$ elements you would like to exclude from the subset containing $1$, which can be accomplished in $\binom{n-1}{r}$ ways. Next, partition those elements into exactly $k-1$ subsets, which can be accomplished in $S(r,k-1)$ ways.

Summing $r$ over the range $0, \dots, n-1$ gives the identity.

Comment: Still confused about how it's possible for $r=0$, in which case no element would be excluded from the subset containing $1$, and the $Y$ subset would not be a partition since it's empty and with no parts.

Comment: In the case of $r=0$, all elements would be included with element $1$. This refers to the partition having a single block containing all $n$ elements.